# JSON-schema exclude properties (opposite to required properties)

Tags: jsonschema

in JSON-schema, one can *require* certain keys in an object, see this example, taken from the [json schema docs](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties):

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "email": { "type": "string" },
    "address": { "type": "string" },
    "telephone": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "required": ["name", "email"]
}
```

I need the opposite: Is there a way to *forbid* or *prevent* a certain key from being in an object? Specifically, I want to prevent users from having an empty key inside an object:

```json
{
    "": "some string value"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can exclude certain keys by name with:

```
{
 "not": {
  "anyOf": [
    { "required": [ "property1" ] },
    { "required": [ "property2" ] },
    { "required": [ "property3" ] },
    ...
  ]
}
```

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html

Answer (score 0):

Next to excluding keys with the `not` syntax (see answer by Ether), it is possible to achieve the goal with [`property-names`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names).

In the following example, all keys have to map to a string URI. We furthermore exclude all keys that are not alphanumeric (via `pattern`), or don't have a specific length (via `minLength`). Other than that, we have no restrictions on keys.

```
"SomeKeyToBeValidated": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": { },
  "propertyNames": {
    "type": "string",
    "minLength": 1,
    "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
  },
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "uri"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `additionalProperties: false` so that the only allowed fields are the ones specified in my json schema.